# How Do I change a link for a mobile browser only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble finding a way to do this. I was told I can use JavaScript or jQuery.
Here's what I have.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) 
{
 document.getElementById('mylink').href = "http://google.com/";
}
</script>
```

Link:

```
<a href="#" id="mylink">
```

I even tried with:

```
<a href="#" id="#mylink">
```

I'm suppose to have the link go to a website on any other browser, but if your on an iPhone go to iTunes link. If someone could help my figure this out I'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Where did you place that script? Before or after your link?

Comment: The script is place before the link itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you could just use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod/))) {
       $("#mylink").prop("href", <istore link>)  
   } else {
       $("#mylink").prop("href", "http://google.com")
   }
});
```

With you anchor tag being

```
<a href="#" id="mylink"></a>
```

I haven't tested this but should be right

**Edit:**
Though i put in enough basic to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Detect mobile like this:

```
 var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/);

if(isMobile) {

   document.getElementById('mylink').href = "http://google.com/";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Browser detection is not recommended, it´s better to use size detection via css media queries. Bootstrap might help you alot:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Class visible ONLY phones: .visible-xs
Class hidden ONLY phones: .hidden-xs

Use the url to learn more.

```
<!--Only Phones-->
<a href="#" class="visible-xs" id="#mylink">

<!--Anything else-->
<a href="#" class="hidden-xs" id="#mylink">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine Marks document ready part with your current code. Also you can test it on your box by selecting firefox and chrome user agents and the JavaScript is much easier to debug in a desktop browser :)

Answer (score 0):

Your script tries to access a DOM element which has not been loaded yet!

```
<script>
  if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) 
  {
   document.getElementById('mylink').href = "http://google.com/";
  }
</script>

<a href="#" id="mylink">
```

**Solutions:**

- Reorder the elements: link tag, then the script tag
- Recommended: Use an event such as `DOMContentLoaded`:

```js
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) 
    {
     document.getElementById('mylink').href = "http://google.com/";
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Should this go in the head sction?

Comment: @DallasClymer The latter code is supposed to fully replace your script tag. Of coures, you can (and should) store the code in a separate JS file.

Comment: I have a limited access to what documents I make, I currently can't make new css or js file for this. Any Alternatives?

Comment: @DallasClymer Then simply replace your script tag by mine.

Comment: I did, didn't do anything.

Comment: Open the developer console of your console (press `F12`) and look for JavaScript errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

try this in userAgent.match('iPhone') instead of / and also where u r having this script either it should be below the a-link tag in html or the best way put it in a function and call it on onload function of body or jquery ready function both should work... Everything else good... Thanks...